# Warning: The PSPDFKit Cocoapod requires an API key. Learn more at https://pspdfkit.com/cocoapods

Tags: objective-c, pspdfkit

Where do I find my API key. License key is very large to use. I have gone  through the documentation provided by https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2017/introducing-pdfxkit/ . However it doesn't explain anything about the error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check how to create How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that you can get a much better response to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The [PSPDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com/) CocoaPods API key can be found in two places:

1. If you are just testing the trial, check iOS on https://pspdfkit.com/try/ and follow the email flow to get the link. This link goes to https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/getting-started/integrating-pspdfkit/ and will pre-fill the page with the trial API key and the trial license key.
2. If you have a valid, paid PSPDFKit subscription license, log into our backend portal at https://customers.pspdfkit.com to get the CocoaPods key. (it's at the very bottom)

If you have further questions, we're here for you over at our support portal at https://pspdfkit.com/support/request/. We try to monitor StackOverflow as well, but using our dedicated support portal will give yiu a much faster response.

[PSPDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com/) is a commercial SDK for viewing, annotating, filling forms and digitally signing PDF documents. This question is about the iOS version, Android, Web, Windows and macOS variants are also available.

Comment: I have read that however just wanted to know the cocoa pod requires a key YOUR_COCOAPODS_KEY_GOES_HERE as per the cocoa pod documentation, where do I find that key. see below


use_frameworks!

target :YourTargetName do
  pod 'PSPDFKit', podspec: 'https://customers.pspdfkit.com/cocoapods/YOUR_COCOAPODS_KEY_GOES_HERE/pspdfkit/latest.podspec'
end

Comment: I have my license key however it requires a your_cocoapod_key what is that

Comment: That key is listed both in the getting started page and our customer portal, just like the license key. Please ping us via https://pspdfkit.com/support/request/ to get faster support.

Comment: I could not see the cocoapod_key , cross checked the same. Hence done through manual integration issue is solved. If possible plz share the screenshot of the page so that in future same can be applied.

Comment: Here's how this looks when you click on the trial link from the email we send, with the cocoapods key pre-filled: https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/0R2P1L3Z000p2Z2y3g0R/Screen%20Shot%202017-12-21%20at%2011.31.11.png?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=08d95d67781b25fd41a557ac404ee01a&v=926c7dd9